# Allow fullscreen (F11'd) program to NOT have focus

Tags: multiple-monitors, cinnamon, fullscreen

I love using F11 for my terminals but sometimes I have another app on the same monitor. Fullscreen apps always fight for focus so if I tab to a third app on my other monitor, the fullscreen one will always pop back on top. Is there anyway to disable this?

For example, on monitor 1 I have chrome open and focused (not fullscreen) and a terminal (fullscreen). I tab to a second terminal on monitor 2. Now the terminal on monitor 1 will become focused and chrome will be under it. What I want is chrome to stay on top.

I'm using cinnamon if that matters.

Thanks.